# SQLite : how to achieve ORM "eager loading" in plain SQL?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with Movies, Actors, and Tags.

There is a many-to-many relation between movies and actors, and movies and tags.

In my app, I want to list all movies with their corresponding actors and tags, for example:

- Mr. & Mrs. Smith: **Actors**: Brad Pitt, Angelina Jolie, **Tags**: Action, Comedy, Crime
- Passengers: **Actors**: Jennifer Lawrence, Chris Pratt, **Tags**: Adventure, Drama, Romance

And I'm wondering what are the correct SQL statements to achieve that.

The tables in my database are defined as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE "Movie" 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE "Actor"  
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE "Tag" 
( 
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE "Movie_Actor" 
( 
    movie_id INTEGER,
    actor_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES "Movie" (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(actor_id) REFERENCES "Actor" (id),
    UNIQUE(movie_id, actor_id)
);

CREATE TABLE "Movie_Tag" 
( 
    movie_id INTEGER,
    tag_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES "Movie" (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(tag_id) REFERENCES "Tag" (id),
    UNIQUE(movie_id, tag_id)
);
```

To get a **single movie** with it's actors and tags I use the following 3 queries (for example Movie.id = 1):

To get the movie row:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Movie 
WHERE id = 1
```

To get the actors:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM Actor) AS T1
JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM Movie_Actor WHERE Movie_Actor.movie_id = 1) AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.actor_id
```

To get tags:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM Tag) AS T1
JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM Movie_Tag WHERE Movie_Tag.movie_id = 1) AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.tag_id
```

My question is, how should I go about retrieving the tags and actors when I'm getting a list of movies such as `SELECT * FROM Movie`?

Many ORMs have an option to 'eager load' relations, and I'm wondering how can I do it in plain SQL?

Do I need to execute extra 2 queries on each row I get from `SELECT * FROM Movie`?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get movie with `id = 1` along with all of the actors associated with that movie you do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Movie
    LEFT JOIN Movie_Actor ON Movie_Actor.movie_id = Movie.id
    LEFT JOIN Actor ON Actor.id = Movie_Actor.actor_id
    WHERE id = 1
```

To also get all the tags, keep joining the associated tables `Movie_Tag` and `Tag`.

You might think that this would be terribly inefficient because a lot of information is going to be duplicated, for example the name of a movie is going to be fetched not just once, but NA * NT times, where NA is the number of fetched actors and NT is the number of fetched tags.

Actually, databases tend to be smart about that, (precisely because this is a very popular mechanism of retrieving data with as few as possible roundtrips to the database,) so within their communication protocols they contain special measures to avoid transmitting field values that are identical from row to row.  So, the actual amount of data transmitted is very close to exactly the amount of data that would have been transmitted if you queried each table separately.

The benefit, of course, is that you suffer the penalty of a single round-trip to the database, instead of several round-trips, one for each table.

Comment: Thank you! this is very helpful. I'm now trying to figure out how to parse the rows I'm getting. Before I was  putting the rows in a <column name> : <column value> Hashmap. So for each returned movie I had a Hashmap with the row's content. This won't fly anymore.

Comment: Yes, the algorithm that decodes the results is a bit involved.  In addition to the columns of `Movie`, your map will need to have two pseudo columns, one for `Actors` and one for `Tags`, whose corresponding values will be collections.

Comment: Yes, I'll probably have to create a specific object for the map that can have both single values and collections. Another problem I'm now confronted with is how to limit the results. Let's say I want to get only 5 movies, the only way I can see of solving this is making a sub-query like `SELECT * FROM Movies LIMIT 5` and only then `JOIN` it with tags and actors...

Comment: This is not valid SQL. And SQLite is not a client/server database, so [using multiple queries is not any slower](http://sqlite.org/np1queryprob.html).

Comment: @CL. So your suggestion is to make 2 separate queries for each `Movie`?
For example when iterating over the results of `SELECT * FROM Movie` query for tags and actors for each row ?

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 Yes, this would be no problem.

Comment: I agree with @CL. that roundtrips would not be a big deal with SQLite.  However, you already have the solution with multiple roundtrips, so I thought that you wanted something different, otherwise there would be no point in this question.  Also, I do see merit in implementing a mechanism that would yield significant benefits in all RDBMSes out there except the in-process ones, and learning something new in doing it.